# Painting a wooden mailbox post

Tags: wood, painting, paint, outdoor, mailbox

I need to repaint my wooden mailbox post.

When I first moved in to my house, the previous owner had let the paint all but come off.  I sprayed it white, with Rust-Oleum spray paint, as that is what "everyone" said in articles on the Internet.  It looked great for a few years.  However, it only took a couple of years to wear.  four years later, it is just a web of cracks and the paint is flaking off.

I live in Virginia, just miles from the Atlantic Ocean.  We get all the weather here.  Hot, cold, humidity, rain, snow, etc.  I assume the cracks are from the wood expanding and contracting from the moisture and temperature swings.

I already bought another can of spray paint and was going to sand the paint off.  However, I am wondering if I should be using primer, or even a different type of paint.

What should I do?

Comment: I would just cover it with cedar boards and never paint it again because you **will** have to paint it again if you choose paint.

Comment: If you do paint then scrape and strip off all of the old flaky paint and use and exterior grade house or deck paint, not spray paint.

Comment: A stain might do better than paint too.

Comment: If having a white woden mailbox post is part of your life plan, repainting it every couple of years should also be part of your life plan. There are other options, such as actually letting all the paint come off (or removing it) and leaving the post to weather, using a plastic-covered post, etc.... Heck, whitewash it every spring, though you might need to make your own whitewash these days. Recipes are out there...

Comment: @alaska man you should make that an answer, I might go oil based but even with a quality exterior house paint it will need repainting but quality exterior paint should last 10-20 years if properly prepped. Never heard of rattle can jobs being recommended for wood.